# C++ templating error: "invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter"

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, static

I have a few thousand lines of code that I am trying to refactor, and I can reduce a lot of code reduplication by combining several of different classes into a single class that handles things by calls on a pointer to external friend classes.

I am running into a problem in that I have a variable `num_var` that counts a number of variables to be used in a calculation, and this changes depending on the external friend class.  This number determined the size of many of my arrays.  With the arrays, I often perform linear algebra with external functions, and these functions are template functions with the template parameter being the size of the array, `num_var`.  I used to have this `static`, but I am no longer able to do that.

I now get an error like this:

```
 candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter
```

Below is a very simple program that reduplicates the compiler error for a much simpler system:

```
#include <iostream>

enum Color {red=0, blue, green};

class Side {//the side of a shape, which can be a color
public:
    Color color;
    friend class Shape;
};

//this function adds numerical value of side colors and prints a value
template <size_t N> int sideNamer(Side sides[N]){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) count += sides[i].color;
    std::cout << "My sides add to " << count << "\n";
    return count;
};

class Shape { //can have an arbitrary number of sides, each a different color
public:
    const int Nsides;
    Side *sides;

    //constructor sets the number of sides and gives a color to each side
    Shape(int N, Color *colors) : Nsides(N){
        sides = new Side[Nsides];
        for(int i=0; i<Nsides; i++) sides[i].color = colors[i];
    };
    ~Shape(){ delete[] sides;};

    //name the sum of the sides
    void nameMySides(){
        sideNamer<Nsides>(sides);
    }
};

int main(){
    //make a triangle: should add to 3
    Color myTriangleColors[3] = {red, blue, green};
    Shape myTriangle(3, myTriangleColors);
    myTriangle.nameMySides();

    //make a square: should add to 2
    Color mySquareColors[4] = {red, red, blue, blue};
    Shape mySquare(4, mySquareColors);
    mySquare.nameMySides();
}
```

This gives me the same error, about an invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter.

When I change the declaration of `Shape` to be a template class, as in

```
template <size_t N> class Shape {
public:
    static const int Nsides = N;
    Side *sides;

    Shape(Color *colors) {
        sides = new Side[Nsides];
        for(int i=0; i<Nsides; i++) sides[i].color = colors[i];
    };
    ~Shape(){ delete[] sides;};

    void nameMySides(){
        sideNamer<Nsides>(sides);
    }
};
```

and *mutando mutandis* then there is no problem and it works.  Sadly, I am not able to do this in my actual program because in some other place in the code I have another class that holds an array of pointers to "`Shape`" objects and I am not able to specify the `size_t' at that point in the code, so I can't be using templates there.

Is there something else I can do to make the template function work?  Also, if it could permit me to declare the `Side` array as `Side sides[Nsides]` instead of as `Side *sides` that would also be greatly appreciated.

How do I work with the template argument when I can't use a template class *or* a `static const`?  Or is there a way to make the template class work in the earlier part of the program?  Do I just have to rewrite the linear algebra functions?

Thanks in advance.

(PS My actual class with the problem is called `Mode`, representing an eigenmode in a physical problem.  It has a pointer to an abstract class called `ModeDriver`, and individual children of `ModeDriver` might have 2, 4, 8, ... variables, the number of which are stored in a variable called `num_var`.  This changes based on physical properties of the particular waveform being modeled.  Several different locations in the code make use of the linear algebra functions.)

Comment: Types are determined at compile time.  Template parameters are part of the type.  Therefore, template parameters cannot depend on runtime values.  It's like asking how to write:  "ask user for a number, input it into a variable X.  If they entered a positive number, the type of X should be unsigned int.  If they input negative, type of X should be signed int."  See the problem?  The type of X must be decided BEFORE the program is run.  That's why N as a template arg works, it's a compile-time value.

Comment: And the fact that the template parameter is part of the type is why I can't make the class a template class, since I have other objects referring to this class without reference to a size parameter.  The size parameter is actually known at compile-time, and is not a runtime value; I just don't know how to specify to the function that needs it what the compile-time value is.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe, nor remember the exact standardese term, that `const int Nsides;` is a valid argument to a template instantiation. That is what the compiler is trying to tell you and exactly what your change to making this a template itself fixes.